# PostgreSQL Accessing multiple database from stored function

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-functions

I want to access different databases from postgresql stored functions.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test ()  RETURNS SETOF volume AS
$BODY$

SELECT * FROM db2.volume
ORDER BY db2.volume.volumeID

$BODY$  
LANGUAGE sql STABLE  
COST 100  
ROWS 1000;
```

any input will be great help.

Regards,
Manasi

Answer (score 2):

what you need is
[database link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html)

Comment: Well but in db link is it possible I can change database name at runtime.

Comment: why not ? SELECT dblink_connect('conn', 'dbname=yourdb');

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (dbname character varying) RETURNS SETOF volume AS $BODY$
SELECT * FROM dblink_connect('dbname=$1') ORDER BY db2.volume.volumeID
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql STABLE
COST 100
ROWS 1000;